# Why the result of the matche is different from the expression?

Tags: c#, regex

The Leetcode have a question:"Given a List of words, return the words that can be typed using letters of alphabet on only one row's of American keyboard.". To solve this, I try to using regular expression in C# like this:

```
    public string[] FindWords(string[] words)
    {
        return words.Where(x => Regex.Match(
         x, @"[qwertyuiop]*|[asdfghjkl]*|[zxcvbnm]*",
         RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Value == x).ToArray();
    }
```

But still cannot get right.For example, when the input like:
["a", "b", "p", "hello"]

I can only get "p" returned.

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is "not right" about it. You need to learn [how to debug small programs before asking a question](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Bad example. No amount of assertions will help one to write a correct regular expression. Yes, test-first approach is good but with certain level of sanity and common sense applied.If I need to write a "Hello World" it is an absolute waste of time to write at least 7 assertions and tests around the method.

Comment: @PhilP. no, its still very relevent. The main peice of advice from the article that would be most helpful would be *"[While stepping through the program] If it does anything that’s not on your list then either your list has a mistake, in which case you didn’t understand what the program does, or your program has a mistake, in which case you coded it wrong. Fix the thing that is wrong. If you don’t know how to fix it, at least now you have a specific technical question you can ask on StackOverflow!"* The OP made a mistake in the regex, if he broke it apart he could figure what is wrong with it.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Ok, thank you, it's my fault, I will fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex pattern is a bit off for what you are trying to achieve. Let's look at it and analyze it.

First, we need to indicate that we're actually trying to match a word, which has a start and an end. It means that we need to prepend the regex with an ***^*** and add ***$*** at the end to indicate string start and end.

Then we need to make sure that we actually have a word, which means there's at least one character. To enforce "one or more character" rule we will need to use ***+*** quantifier instead of *****.

Lastly, the Regex pattern you're trying to use does not ensure that we are using characters from ***only*** one row. It does ensure that for each capturing group (sections between the OR operator) but we end up having as many capturing groups as there are scenarios that should invalidate the string. Which basically means that the following word will still validate:

```
today
```

The Regex will match three capturing groups: "to", "da" and "y". Instead, we need to explicitly set the grouping.
I've ended up with the following pattern:

```
^([qwertyuiop]+|[asdfghjkl]+|[zxcvbnm]+)$
```

Comment: Thanks! I used a day to verify the expression and repeatedly view  the document of the Match function but still can not get right ....I seem to understand the regular expression is not enough familiar with... Thanks again for your very helpful answer!

Comment: @overflow I strongly recommend https://regex101.com/ for building and validating Regex expressions. It provides very helpful explanations on how the Regex is actually processed (on the right side), saved me with complex expressions many times.

Comment: Thank you for providing the site, which is very valuable for the novice